# Android app suspends/crashes when add new code inside OnCreate

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I'm doing a simple news and videos with tabs app but I'm having problems when I add a `onClickListener` to change to another page, right after I add the code it the app suspends after it is launched, but when I remove it, it works fine and It happens with any other method like

```js
 test.setText("etc");
```

The method I created is `addListener()`; and I tried it in other app and works perfectly but in this one it just makes the app suspend.
If someone could help me would be very nice cause I've been stuck here since some days.

Also sorry for my English I hope you can understand what I'm trying to say.

Here is the code of the main activity

```js
package com.example.link_test;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  ViewPager Tab;
    TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
  ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                      actionBar = getActionBar();
                      actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    }
                });
        Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){
      @Override
      public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
          FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
      @Override
       public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
              Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
          }
      @Override
      public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
          FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }};
      //Add New Tab
      actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("News").setTabListener(tabListener));
      actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Videos").setTabListener(tabListener));
      actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(tabListener));
      addListener();
    }
    public void addListener() {
        final View tab1 = (View) findViewById(R.layout.tab1);
        LinearLayout newLink = (LinearLayout) tab1.findViewById(R.id.news1);
        newLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView testText = (TextView) tab1.findViewById(R.id.newstext1);
                testText.setText("This text has been modfied");
            }
        });
   }
    }
```

This TabAdapterPager class that manages the tabs

```
package com.example.link_test;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            //Fragement for Android Tab
            return new Tab1();
        case 1:
           //Fragment for Ios Tab
            return new Tab2();
        case 2:
            //Fragment for Windows Tab
            return new Tab3(); 
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }
}
```

This is the Tab1.java

```
package com.example.link_test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
          public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              final View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

              LinearLayout newLink = (LinearLayout) android.findViewById(R.id.news1);
              newLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    TextView text1 = (TextView) android.findViewById(R.id.newstext1);
                    text1.setText("This text has been modified");

                }
                });

              return android;
    }  
}
```

This is  tab1.xml that has the layout that contains the "button"

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            tools:context="com.example.test.test$PlaceholderFragment"
            >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragNew"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <!-- This is the 1st part of the new -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/news1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:contentDescription="image3"
                        android:src="@drawable/rsl" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/newstext1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:fontFamily="tahoma"
                            android:text="This will be the tittle of the new, if is too long  it&apos;ll be ... at the end"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|center|bottom"
                            android:text="Date: 4/31/2014"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <!-- This is the end of the 1st new -->

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/View01"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />
                <!-- The next new separated by a view item -->


            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

This is Activity's XML

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

These are all the lines that appear when I debug the app at LogCat:

```
04-24 07:47:02.618: D/AndroidRuntime(1435): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-24 07:47:02.688: D/AndroidRuntime(1435): CheckJNI is ON
04-24 07:47:03.088: D/dalvikvm(1435): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
04-24 07:47:03.118: D/dalvikvm(1435): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
04-24 07:47:03.188: D/dalvikvm(1435): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
04-24 07:47:03.188: D/dalvikvm(1435): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
04-24 07:47:03.198: D/dalvikvm(1435): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
04-24 07:47:03.718: D/dalvikvm(1435): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
04-24 07:47:04.518: D/LightsService(384): Excessive delay setting light: 266ms
04-24 07:47:04.588: D/LightsService(384): Excessive delay setting light: 68ms
04-24 07:47:04.728: D/LightsService(384): Excessive delay setting light: 137ms
04-24 07:47:04.798: D/LightsService(384): Excessive delay setting light: 68ms
04-24 07:47:05.498: E/memtrack(1435): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>04-24 07:47:05.498: E/android.os.Debug(1435): failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-24 07:47:06.008: D/AndroidRuntime(1435): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
04-24 07:47:06.128: D/AndroidRuntime(1435): Shutting down VM
04-24 07:47:06.148: D/dalvikvm(1435): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-24 07:47:08.278: D/AndroidRuntime(1446): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-24 07:47:08.298: D/AndroidRuntime(1446): CheckJNI is ON
04-24 07:47:08.448: D/dalvikvm(1446): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
04-24 07:47:08.468: D/dalvikvm(1446): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
04-24 07:47:08.518: D/dalvikvm(1446): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
04-24 07:47:08.528: D/dalvikvm(1446): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
04-24 07:47:08.528: D/dalvikvm(1446): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
04-24 07:47:08.928: D/dalvikvm(1446): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
>04-24 07:47:10.008: E/memtrack(1446): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>04-24 07:47:10.008: E/android.os.Debug(1446): failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-24 07:47:10.568: D/AndroidRuntime(1446): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
04-24 07:47:10.708: I/ActivityManager(384): Force stopping com.example.link_test appid=10062 user=-1: set debug app
04-24 07:47:10.718: I/ActivityManager(384): Killing 1422:com.example.link_test/u0a62 (adj 0): stop com.example.link_test
04-24 07:47:10.758: I/ActivityManager(384):   Force finishing activity ActivityRecord{b306fee8 u0 com.example.link_test/.MainActivity t5}
04-24 07:47:11.108: I/ActivityManager(384): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.link_test/.MainActivity} from pid 1446
04-24 07:47:11.318: D/AndroidRuntime(1446): Shutting down VM
04-24 07:47:11.368: D/dalvikvm(1446): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-24 07:47:11.438: I/Choreographer(384): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-24 07:47:11.808: I/Choreographer(1382): Skipped 211 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-24 07:47:11.828: W/ActivityManager(384): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b2d157a0 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher t1}
04-24 07:47:11.948: I/ActivityManager(384): Start proc com.example.link_test for activity com.example.link_test/.MainActivity: pid=1457 uid=10062 gids={50062}
04-24 07:47:11.988: D/dalvikvm(1457): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-24 07:47:13.508: I/Choreographer(384): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-24 07:47:13.688: I/Choreographer(384): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-24 07:47:13.698: W/ActivityThread(1457): Application com.example.link_test is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
04-24 07:47:13.718: I/System.out(1457): Sending WAIT chunk
04-24 07:47:13.828: I/dalvikvm(1457): Debugger is active
04-24 07:47:13.968: I/Choreographer(384): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-24 07:47:14.018: I/System.out(1457): Debugger has connected
04-24 07:47:14.018: I/System.out(1457): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-24 07:47:14.228: I/System.out(1457): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-24 07:47:14.468: I/System.out(1457): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-24 07:47:14.668: I/System.out(1457): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-24 07:47:14.918: I/System.out(1457): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-24 07:47:15.048: I/Choreographer(384): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-24 07:47:15.168: I/System.out(1457): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-24 07:47:15.368: I/System.out(1457): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-24 07:47:15.488: I/Choreographer(384): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-24 07:47:15.568: I/System.out(1457): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-24 07:47:15.638: I/Choreographer(384): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-24 07:47:15.768: I/System.out(1457): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-24 07:47:15.998: I/System.out(1457): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-24 07:47:16.348: I/System.out(1457): debugger has settled (1382)
04-24 07:47:16.558: I/Choreographer(384): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-24 07:47:16.958: I/Choreographer(384): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-24 07:47:17.118: I/Choreographer(384): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-24 07:47:17.888: D/dalvikvm(1382): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 845K, 15% free 5705K/6652K, paused 2424ms, total 2433ms
04-24 07:47:18.108: D/dalvikvm(1457): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 52K, 5% free 2953K/3080K, paused 58ms, total 64ms
04-24 07:47:18.108: I/dalvikvm-heap(1457): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.558MB for 635812-byte allocation
04-24 07:47:18.238: D/dalvikvm(1457): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3571K/3704K, paused 66ms, total 66ms
04-24 07:47:21.288: W/ActivityManager(384): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
>04-24 07:47:21.438: E/WindowManager(384): Starting window AppWindowToken{b2f7e518 token=Token{b30ee228 ActivityRecord{b2fcdcf0 u0 com.example.link_test/.MainActivity t6}}} timed out
```

Comment: You have to check your logcat for a class of your project and a line number, where the exception was thrown, in order to understand exactly where your bug is occurring.

Comment: Does your app receive a ANR (application not responding)? Does the layout change?

Comment: This part of the log cat is completely unhelpful. Look for where the log cat is red or where it specifically gives you an error or a line number.

Comment: I uploaded the LongCat code with the events that happen when I debug the app. Also when I try to click on the black screen the ANR error appears. Thanks you all for your help, I really wonder why adding a fully functional setContentView or event a setText makes the app crash like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this line:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.news_content);
```

Once you set conentView you cannot change it again with a button.

To use set content view again, you must open new activity or reopen the current activity.

**Edit**:

in xml your view is type of LinearLayout.

In your code its should be like this:

```
LinearLayout newLink = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.news1);
```

instead of this:

```
View newLink = (View) findViewById(R.id.news1);
```

**Edit2**:

now when im looking on your main activity xml ,
you are using it wrong!
You must put the view pager as a second view and not as a root.

like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit3**:

Why would you put a click listener to a linear layout? also in your main activity xml i cannot find any textview..
you cannot refer to a textview which is outside of your current activity.
If you look in your tab1.xml you will find that the textview you are trying to set is there.

**Edit4:**

Example for using method findViewById inside fragment:
Button b =(Button) android.findViewById (R.id.yourbutton)
Make sure to write this after your View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the app crash even if I only add a var.setText(String); inside the onCreate or event at my method of addListener. I'll upload another app where this code works perfectly.

Comment: Hey look in your xml - its should be LinearLayout and not View like you did in your code

Comment: @SacreDevekioer That works well but the problem in my main app persist, I really think that the problem is that I have to use activity_main instead of fragment_activity but I don't know where

Comment: Oh I am sorry I got it wrong, I had commented my method at MainActivity and since it wasn't called it worked x_x but the problem persist though I am learning more now

Comment: But you got it work now? if yes you can still accept my answer :)

Comment: Your code works well but this problem persist for somereason, do you think that I am doing my addListener method properly? or in this case you have to specify this.newLink.setOnClickListener... or so?

Comment: I am sure that is the problem, the tab1.xml has the fields I am refering to but surely the method I am using to reach/modify them is wrong, the main_activity is the pager of my tabs. Also I use a layout as listener cause when I click on it I get redirected to another xml that has the full information of the new.

Comment: Ok, but you cannot put on click listener to a view which is not in the main activity xml. you must use the container of that view. for example, if its in fragment, to find the button you will use: Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.); view is the fragment

Comment: I edited my method of addListener to add the view but it's still crashing, do you think am I doing it right?

Comment: Yes, because tab1 is a fragment, which mean - your code of clickListener should be in your fragment class which is tab1.

Comment: I see now, but I have another problem. findViewById(); is a method of Activity so I can't use it inside Tab1.java cause is a fragment. Is there another way to find the R.id or to extend Activity to my Tab1 to make it work?

Comment: You can use it like this: Button b =(Button) android.findView....       Make sure to write this after your   View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);;

Comment: Now it works like a charm, I updated my Tab1.java so hopefully this can help people who have problems like these, Thanks a lot for your help now I can say I've learned a lot