# android - App crashes after adding code to onCreate

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on an Android app. For some reason, whenever I add any code to the onCreate, the app crashes on launch.

Here is what Eclipse generates:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle exampleApp) {
    super.onCreate(exampleApp);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (exampleApp == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

}
```

With that it launches just fine, but obviously it doesn't really do anything. As soon as I add code to make a button do something, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle exampleApp) {
    super.onCreate(exampleApp);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (exampleApp == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    final Button doSomething = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doSomethingButton);
    doSomething.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Insert code to execute on button press here
        }
    });

}
```

The app crashes on launch. I have no idea what is going on, as according to all the documentation I can find, I am doing it correctly, and I have actually made apps before this way, so what the hell is wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: i guess this final Button doSomething = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doSomethingButton) button is not present in activity_main.xml but in fragment_placeholder.xml right?

Comment: Post your logcat also.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in uisng `setContentView()`.Once the `setContentView()` is set you cannot associate with the button again

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250715/android-app-suspends-crashes-when-add-new-code-inside-oncreate) one.